# CloudWatch Logs Insights get average of count returned

Tags: average, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm querying CloudWatch logs via Logs Insights queries and am trying to get the average for count returned. For example, my current query that gets the counts is (only relevant parts shown):

```
fields fieldA as A
| stats count(*) as countForEachA by A
```

returns this:

```
  A    countForEachA
______ _____________
a123      22
a124      22
a125      16
```

I'm trying to get the average for field `countForEachA`. Therefore, for the example above, I want the average: 20 (sum of countForEachA divided by total results). Here's what I've tried:

```
fields fieldA as A
| stats avg(count(*)) as average by A
```

The query above returns this:

```
  A    countForEachA
______ _____________
a123      2.3
a124      1.4
a125      2.9
```

while I expected a single answer representing the average. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it, to get the average for countForEachA, we first need to get the count value and then simply call the `avg()` function like so:

```
fields fieldA as A
| stats count(*) as countForEachA, avg(countForEachA)
```

Hope this helps others.

Comment: But with this you're not grouping by A any longer, no?

Comment: This use case keeps popping up for me. Rauññ is right, you've dropped the group by A here and it makes all the difference. I have not yet found a way to group by X and then average. For instance, if you've got request logs, to take max latency for a session across all pages and then get the average of that value across all sessions.